# Is there a list of public release dates for certain top level domains?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, top-level-domains

I want to register a .man domain but I have no idea when its going to be available.

and is it possible to pre-register this domain name? when i search for it on namecheap or godaddy no .man domains come up.

Comment: You can search for the _sunrise_ period for new domain extensions at ICANN, which is required to be 30 days prior to release. After that, the Registry will indicate when the domain extensions they oversee are released to Registrars (e.g., GoDaddy). [Donuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donuts_%28corporation%29) is the acting Registry for many of the new Top Level Domains, and lists their release date for extensions [here](http://www.donuts.domains/services/domain-names).

Comment: I do not see `.man` listed there or in ICANN, so that may not be pending release at this time (or possibly in the future, despite what some sites might indicate).

Comment: i see some domain registrars such as Intstra.com and mrdomain.com allowing pre-registration for the .man TLD. Does this mean that they are simply speculating that it will exist in the future? Are either of these trusted domain registrars?

Comment: My guess would be _speculating_, since ICANN would need to approve the gTLD first, followed by the sunrise period to make sure trademarks are not being infringed upon. You can search for gTLDs and Sunrise Information [here](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods).

Comment: damn, now i'll never know when i can register my domain name...

Comment: `.man` would seem to be a _brand TLD_ which is unlikely to be made available for public registration. Reference: http://icannwiki.com/.man and https://www.101domain.com/man.htm

Comment: Isn't that against the public interest commitment? Man is too generic of a string.

Comment: @user8363 I find the whole new gTLD policies and everything fairly stupid.  I would assume if Man is to generic of a string then Apple would be also.  Both have passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look here. It seems to be updated periodically .

https://www.onlydomains.com/domains/new/launch-diary#launchDiary

Answer (score 1):

Do not be fooled by anyone trying to sell you their services or by using third party information.

ICANN is in charge of accreditating new registries and opening new TLDs. This should be the only source you take as authoritative on this matter.

Go to http://gtldresult.icann.org/application-result/applicationstatus to track status of all current new gTLDs.

You can also use this other page: https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods to have dates (as communicated by the registries themselves) on their opening in progressive phases.

Do not get involved in any kind of pre-reservation/preorder scheme. There is nothing guaranteed there for the end users, so better wait from **registries** announcements when their TLD open.

As for `.man` you can see on https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/man.html that it went live (published in the root zone) around 2015-02-27. You can see its other dates at https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods/man but it is a "brand" TLD, so very restricted, as owned by a company for its single use. In short, you as an individual will never be able to buy a domain name there.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up to all the answers,
There is a way to get the release time notification of all new TLDs.
**Getting a reseller account at resellerclub or any other domain provider.**
You will be timely notified plus you will get great discounts.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.name.com/preorder brought me to **http://www.trademark-clearinghouse.com/gtld-calendar**, which seems like it's probably real.